# This exercise is solved using the fundamental theorem of calculus?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function that satisfies the following conditions

a) $f$ is continuous

b)  $f$ is positive

c) $f$ is pair

d) $\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)dt=6$.

Prove that there $\epsilon > 0$ and a function $g:[0,\epsilon)\rightarrow [0,\infty)$  such that

$$\int_{x}^{g(x)}f(t)dt=1.$$

Calculate $g'(x)$.

From my point of view the hypothesis b) and c) are just for that  $\int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt=3$... I know all adicionamlmente $f$
  be a continuous real-valued function defined on a closed interval [a, b]. Let $F$ be the function defined, for all x in [a, b], by
$$F(x) = \int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt.$$

Then, $F$ is uniformly continuous on $[a, b]$, differentiable on the open interval $(a, b)$, and
$F'(x) = f(x)\,$ for all $x$ in $(a, b).$..  but I do not know how I can use this result in the problem.

Comment: Do you mean that the integral is 1 for every $x$?

Comment: What do you mean by $f$ is pair?

Comment: "pair" is French for "even": $f(-x) = f(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $F(x_1,x_2):=\int_{x_1}^{x_2} f.$ Then, $D_2f(x_1,x_2)=f(x_2)$ (where $D_2f$ is the partial derivative with respect to the second variable), and $D_1 f(x_1,x_2)=-f(x_1)$ due to the fundamental theorem of calculus. The hypotheses over $f$ guarantee that the implicit function theorem can be applied. You just need to get a first $y$ so that $\int_0^y f=1$. But this is simple, since  $\int_0^1 f=3$ as you conclude, and then it follows from the intermediate value theorem (applied to $\int_0^xf$) that there is such a $y$.

As to $g'(x)$, note that $\int_x^{g(x)}f=1 \implies \int_0^{g(x)} f- \int_0^x f=1 \implies f(g(x))\cdot g'(x) -f(x)=0 \implies g'(x)=\frac{f(x)}{f(g(x))}.$